# Angular: When deleting some HTML, included ng-controller isn't being $destroyed

Tags: angularjs

For some reason, I need to have a button that removes part of the page's HTML with jQuery, like so: `$('#sss').remove();`

My problem is that if there's a controller inside #sss, then the `$destroy` event isn't called.

How can I make sure the `$destroy` event occurs for each and every controller inside #sss ?

Thanks

P.S. I guess another way to put the question might be: how does $state and $route do it?

Comment: can you remove it with the angular elements method instead? `element.remove()`. that might take the angular specific events into account. never tried tho.

Comment: How can I set element to equal $('#sss') ?

Comment: @Jorg no, that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the scope or isolatedScope if your element belongs to a directive with isolated scope for the element and then invoke the de destroy method in it something like.

```
 var el=angular.element('#ssss');
 el.scope().$destroy();
 //el.isolatedScope().$destroy();
 el.remove();
```

note that the commented line is just for isolated scopes and if that's the case then the first scope getting line is not needed.

## LINKS

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy

Comment: Thanks. I just have to take care, then, to create a scope on the exact element #ssss, so that the parent scope isn't destroyed instead. Creating a scope on element #sss can be done by adding an ng-controller on it. Correct?

Comment: yes i just updated my response with AngularJS docs link where you can read more about it

Comment: I created a directive that creates a scope, with scope: true, and use that to create a scope instead of creating a controller which is more work.